# Qt 4.8.4 Release version not working on Windows 7 64 bit

Tags: c++, qt, release

I am trying to make a releasable version of a project. I tested the exe with the dlls included in the same directory on several different machines. It is running on my computer (windows 8 64 bit), a 32 bit windows xp virtual machine, a 32 bit windows 7 virtual machine, and another windows 7 64 bit laptop. Someone else, however, is trying to run it on another windows 7 64 bit machine. He is getting a Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library error that says:

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate in an unusual way. Please contact the application's support team for more information.

dlls I'm including in the application's directory:

```
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll
libstdc++-6.dll
mingwm10.dll
QtCore4.dll
QtCored4.dll
QtGui4.dll
QtNetwork4.dll
QtSerialPortd.dll
```

This is what a ldd on the exe file looks like on my windows 8 computer where it is working:

```
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7fc44b50000)
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77730000)
wow64.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/wow64.dll (0x776e0000)
wow64win.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/wow64win.dll (0x77670000)
wow64cpu.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/wow64cpu.dll (0x776d0000)
??? => ??? (0x540000)
KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x75680000)
??? => ??? (0x540000)
??? => ??? (0x540000)
KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x75680000)
KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x76da0000)
msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/msvcrt.dll (0x76ba0000)
WSOCK32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WSOCK32.DLL (0x747e0000)
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll => /cygdrive/c/Mingw32/bin/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (0x6e940000)
libstdc++-6.dll => /cygdrive/c/Mingw32/bin/libstdc++-6.dll (0x6fc40000)
QtCore4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtCore4.dll (0x6e0c0000)
QtGui4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtGui4.dll (0x67700000)
QtNetwork4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtNetwork4.dll (0x65c80000)
QtSerialPortd.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtSerialPortd.dll (0x63680000)
WS2_32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WS2_32.dll (0x76e50000)
ADVAPI32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ADVAPI32.DLL (0x74e60000)
mingwm10.dll => /cygdrive/c/Mingw32/bin/mingwm10.dll (0x6fbc0000)
OLE32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/OLE32.dll (0x74f20000)
USER32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/USER32.dll (0x76c80000)
COMDLG32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/COMDLG32.DLL (0x75800000)
GDI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/GDI32.dll (0x75250000)
IMM32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/IMM32.DLL (0x76eb0000)
OLEAUT32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/OLEAUT32.DLL (0x76ed0000)
SHELL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SHELL32.DLL (0x75ad0000)
WINMM.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WINMM.DLL (0x747b0000)
WINSPOOL.DRV => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WINSPOOL.DRV (0x73800000)
setupapi.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/setupapi.dll (0x750a0000)
QtCored4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtCored4.dll (0x69cc0000)
RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/RPCRT4.dll (0x775c0000)
NSI.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/NSI.dll (0x76ea0000)
sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/sechost.dll (0x77510000)
combase.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/combase.dll (0x753d0000)
SHLWAPI.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SHLWAPI.dll (0x75a90000)
COMCTL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/WinSxS/x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9200.16658_none_bf1359a245f1cd12/COMCTL32.dll (0x73cd0000)
MSCTF.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/MSCTF.dll (0x74d80000)
WINMMBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WINMMBASE.dll (0x74780000)
CFGMGR32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/CFGMGR32.dll (0x77020000)
DEVOBJ.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/DEVOBJ.dll (0x77070000)
SspiCli.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SspiCli.dll (0x74d60000)
CRYPTBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/CRYPTBASE.dll (0x74d50000)
SHCORE.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SHCORE.DLL (0x74700000)
bcryptPrimitives.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/bcryptPrimitives.dll (0x74cf0000)
```

Edit:

I rebuilt the release version on an XP machine. It looks like the libstdc++-6.dll is no longer showing up in ldd.

ldd on the 32 bit Windows XP machine it was built on (working):

```
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ntdll.dll (0x7c900000)
kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/kernel32.dll (0x7c800000)
QtCore4.dll => /cygdrive/c/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/QtCore4.dll (0x6a1c0000)
ADVAPI32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/ADVAPI32.DLL (0x77dd0000)
RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/RPCRT4.dll (0x77e70000)
Secur32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/Secur32.dll (0x77fe0000)
mingwm10.dll => /cygdrive/c/QtSDK/mingw/bin/mingwm10.dll (0x6fbc0000)
msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/msvcrt.dll (0x77c10000)
OLE32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/OLE32.dll (0x774e0000)
GDI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/GDI32.dll (0x77f10000)
USER32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/USER32.dll (0x7e410000)
WS2_32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WS2_32.DLL (0x71ab0000)
WS2HELP.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WS2HELP.dll (0x71aa0000)
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll => /cygdrive/c/QtSDK/mingw/bin/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (0x6e940000)
QtGui4.dll => /cygdrive/c/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/QtGui4.dll (0x65100000)
COMDLG32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/COMDLG32.DLL (0x763b0000)
COMCTL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/COMCTL32.dll (0x5d090000)
SHELL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/SHELL32.dll (0x7c9c0000)
SHLWAPI.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/SHLWAPI.dll (0x77f60000)
IMM32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/IMM32.DLL (0x76390000)
OLEAUT32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/OLEAUT32.DLL (0x77120000)
WINMM.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WINMM.DLL (0x76b40000)
WINSPOOL.DRV => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WINSPOOL.DRV (0x73000000)
QtNetwork4.dll => /cygdrive/c/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/QtNetwork4.dll (0x6ff00000)
QtSerialPortd.dll => /cygdrive/c/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/QtSerialPortd.dll (0x6ef80000)
QtCored4.dll => /cygdrive/c/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.7.4/mingw/bin/QtCored4.dll (0x680000)
setupapi.dll => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/setupapi.dll (0x77920000)
WSOCK32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/WINDOWS/system32/WSOCK32.DLL (0x71ad0000)
```

ldd on the Windows 8 computer (working) :

```
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x7fc44b50000)
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x77730000)
wow64.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/wow64.dll (0x776e0000)
wow64win.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/wow64win.dll (0x77670000)
wow64cpu.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/wow64cpu.dll (0x776d0000)
??? => ??? (0x2b0000)
KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x75680000)
??? => ??? (0x2b0000)
??? => ??? (0x2b0000)
KERNEL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNEL32.DLL (0x75680000)
KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/KERNELBASE.dll (0x76da0000)
apphelp.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/system32/apphelp.dll (0x73de0000)
msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/msvcrt.dll (0x76ba0000)
WSOCK32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WSOCK32.DLL (0x747e0000)
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/jared/documents/telkonet/ESU Release/test/esutest/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (0x6e940000)
libstdc++-6.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/jared/documents/telkonet/ESU Release/test/esutest/libstdc++-6.dll (0x6fc40000)
QtCore4.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/jared/documents/telkonet/ESU Release/test/esutest/QtCore4.dll (0x6e0c0000)
QtGui4.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/jared/documents/telkonet/ESU Release/test/esutest/QtGui4.dll (0x67700000)
QtNetwork4.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/jared/documents/telkonet/ESU Release/test/esutest/QtNetwork4.dll (0x65c80000)
QtSerialPortd.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/jared/documents/telkonet/ESU Release/test/esutest/QtSerialPortd.dll (0x63680000)
WS2_32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WS2_32.dll (0x76e50000)
ADVAPI32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/ADVAPI32.DLL (0x74e60000)
mingwm10.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/jared/documents/telkonet/ESU Release/test/esutest/mingwm10.dll (0x6fbc0000)
OLE32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/OLE32.dll (0x74f20000)
USER32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/USER32.dll (0x76c80000)
COMDLG32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/COMDLG32.DLL (0x75800000)
GDI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/GDI32.dll (0x75250000)
IMM32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/IMM32.DLL (0x76eb0000)
OLEAUT32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/OLEAUT32.DLL (0x76ed0000)
SHELL32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SHELL32.DLL (0x75ad0000)
WINMM.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WINMM.DLL (0x747b0000)
WINSPOOL.DRV => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WINSPOOL.DRV (0x73800000)
setupapi.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/setupapi.dll (0x750a0000)
QtCored4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Qt/4.8.4/bin/QtCored4.dll (0x69cc0000)
RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/RPCRT4.dll (0x775c0000)
NSI.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/NSI.dll (0x76ea0000)
sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/sechost.dll (0x77510000)
combase.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/combase.dll (0x753d0000)
SHLWAPI.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SHLWAPI.dll (0x75a90000)
COMCTL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/WinSxS/x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.9200.16658_none_bf1359a245f1cd12/COMCTL32.dll (0x73cd0000)
MSCTF.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/MSCTF.dll (0x74d80000)
WINMMBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/WINMMBASE.dll (0x74780000)
CFGMGR32.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/CFGMGR32.dll (0x77020000)
DEVOBJ.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/DEVOBJ.dll (0x77070000)
SspiCli.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SspiCli.dll (0x74d60000)
CRYPTBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/CRYPTBASE.dll (0x74d50000)
SHCORE.DLL => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/SHCORE.DLL (0x74700000)
bcryptPrimitives.dll => /cygdrive/c/windows/SYSTEM32/bcryptPrimitives.dll (0x74cf0000)
```

ldd on the Windows 7 64 bit (working):

```
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x76f30000)
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/ntdll.dll (0x77110000)
wow64.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64.dll (0x72c50000)
wow64win.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64win.dll (0x72bf0000)
wow64cpu.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64cpu.dll (0x72be0000)
??? => ??? (0x76d10000)
kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll (0x75670000)
??? => ??? (0x76d10000)
??? => ??? (0x76e30000)
kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll (0x75670000)
KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KERNELBASE.dll (0x76a30000)
QtCore4.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/admin/downloads/esutestexe/QtCore4.dll (0x6a1c0000)
ADVAPI32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/ADVAPI32.DLL (0x74c90000)
msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/msvcrt.dll (0x75570000)
sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/sechost.dll (0x74f70000)
RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/RPCRT4.dll (0x75480000)
SspiCli.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/SspiCli.dll (0x74b60000)
CRYPTBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/CRYPTBASE.dll (0x74b50000)
mingwm10.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/admin/downloads/esutestexe/mingwm10.dll (0x6fbc0000)
OLE32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/OLE32.dll (0x768c0000)
GDI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/GDI32.dll (0x76c80000)
USER32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/USER32.dll (0x76740000)
LPK.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/LPK.dll (0x74fe0000)
USP10.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/USP10.dll (0x74bc0000)
WS2_32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/WS2_32.DLL (0x74f90000)
NSI.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/NSI.dll (0x76a20000)
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/admin/downloads/esutestexe/libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll (0x6e940000)
QtGui4.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/admin/downloads/esutestexe/QtGui4.dll (0x65100000)
COMDLG32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/COMDLG32.DLL (0x764c0000)
SHLWAPI.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/SHLWAPI.dll (0x76b20000)
COMCTL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/WinSxS/x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5/COMCTL32.dll (0x72010000)
SHELL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/SHELL32.dll (0x75790000)
IMM32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/IMM32.DLL (0x76840000)
MSCTF.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/MSCTF.dll (0x763e0000)
OLEAUT32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/OLEAUT32.DLL (0x76a90000)
WINMM.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/WINMM.DLL (0x725b0000)
WINSPOOL.DRV => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/WINSPOOL.DRV (0x720a0000)
QtNetwork4.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/admin/downloads/esutestexe/QtNetwork4.dll (0x6ff00000)
QtSerialPortd.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/admin/downloads/esutestexe/QtSerialPortd.dll (0x6ef80000)
QtCored4.dll => /cygdrive/c/users/admin/downloads/esutestexe/QtCored4.dll (0x7f0000)
setupapi.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/setupapi.dll (0x74ff0000)
CFGMGR32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/CFGMGR32.dll (0x74d40000)
DEVOBJ.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/DEVOBJ.dll (0x768a0000)
WSOCK32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/WSOCK32.DLL (0x661d0000)
```

ldd on the Windows 7 64 bit machine (not working):

```
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/ntdll.dll (0x76cf0000)
ntdll.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/ntdll.dll (0x76ed0000)
wow64.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64.dll (0x748b0000)
wow64win.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64win.dll (0x74850000)
wow64cpu.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64cpu.dll (0x74840000)
??? => ??? (0x76ad0000)
kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll (0x76560000)
??? => ??? (0x76ad0000)
??? => ??? (0x76bf0000)
kernel32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/kernel32.dll (0x76560000)
KERNELBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/KERNELBASE.dll (0x7522000                                                                                         0)
QtCore4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/bschwanke/Desktop/ESUtestEXE/QtCore4.dl                                                                                         l (0x6a1c0000)
ADVAPI32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/ADVAPI32.DLL (0x74a70000)
msvcrt.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/msvcrt.dll (0x74e10000)
sechost.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/SysWOW64/sechost.dll (0x76ab0000)
RPCRT4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/RPCRT4.dll (0x75130000)
SspiCli.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/SspiCli.dll (0x74920000)
CRYPTBASE.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/CRYPTBASE.dll (0x74910000)
mingwm10.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/bschwanke/Desktop/ESUtestEXE/mingwm10.                                                                                         dll (0x6fbc0000)
OLE32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/OLE32.dll (0x76390000)
GDI32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/GDI32.dll (0x749e0000)
USER32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/USER32.dll (0x761a0000)
LPK.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/LPK.dll (0x76ea0000)
USP10.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/USP10.dll (0x75270000)
WS2_32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/WS2_32.DLL (0x74b10000)
NSI.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/NSI.dll (0x74ec0000)
libgcc_s_dw2-1.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/bschwanke/Desktop/ESUtestEXE/lib                                                                                         gcc_s_dw2-1.dll (0x6e940000)
QtGui4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/bschwanke/Desktop/ESUtestEXE/QtGui4.dll                                                                                          (0x65100000)
COMDLG32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/COMDLG32.DLL (0x76680000)
SHLWAPI.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/SHLWAPI.dll (0x74ee0000)
COMCTL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/WinSxS/x86_microsoft.windows.common-                                                                                         controls_6595b64144ccf1df_5.82.7601.18201_none_ec80f00e8593ece5/COMCTL32.dll (0x                                                                                         733e0000)
SHELL32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/SHELL32.dll (0x753b0000)
IMM32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/IMM32.DLL (0x74980000)
MSCTF.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/MSCTF.dll (0x762b0000)
OLEAUT32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/OLEAUT32.DLL (0x767a0000)
WINMM.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/WINMM.DLL (0x73e80000)
WINSPOOL.DRV => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/WINSPOOL.DRV (0x74240000)
QtNetwork4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/bschwanke/Desktop/ESUtestEXE/QtNetwo                                                                                         rk4.dll (0x6ff00000)
QtSerialPortd.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/bschwanke/Desktop/ESUtestEXE/QtSe                                                                                         rialPortd.dll (0x6ef80000)
QtCored4.dll => /cygdrive/c/Users/bschwanke/Desktop/ESUtestEXE/QtCored4.                                                                                         dll (0x780000)
setupapi.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/setupapi.dll (0x76000000)
CFGMGR32.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/CFGMGR32.dll (0x76770000)
DEVOBJ.dll => /cygdrive/c/Windows/syswow64/DEVOBJ.dll (0x74df0000)
WSOCK32.DLL => /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/WSOCK32.DLL (0x73120000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Does the computer that is giving you the Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library have the Microsoft Visual C++ redistributable package installed on it?  Any computer that does not have the same version of the compiler used to build your program will need the redist package installed so that the executable can load those libraries at runtime.

[This page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2019667) has links to the various redist packages available for download.

Also, with your list of distributed DLLs, you have both QtCore4.dll and QtCored4.dll.  The one with a 'd' is a debug DLL and won't be loaded by your Release-built executable.  You are also only distributing the debug version of QtSerialPortd.dll, so you should switch that over to the release version as well (drop the 'd').

Comment: Comparing the Windows 7 64 bit that does work, and the one that doesn't work... In programs and features, both machines seem to be identical except the one that is working has "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x86 Redistributable" as well as a x64 Redistributable. The machine that is not working only has "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 x64 Redistributable" and does not have the x86 Redistributable.

Comment: Having had similar problems in the past, Dependency Walker is a great help to resolve these issues.

Comment: Jared, if you built your program as a 32-bit executable (and it would seem that you certainly had to given that it is running on 32-bit machines), then not having the x86 Redistributable package is likely the problem. Try installing the x86 Redist package and see if that fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Well I figured it out. It is an issue with DB9 serial com port.

The application uses serial port connections to a device. The computer it wasn't working on had an old DB9 serial port on it. The other computers only had USB ports. When we plugged in a DB9 serial cable the application ran just fine.

There are some 3rd party libraries dealing with some of the serial port stuff so I'll have to take a look at that.